# How to sort strings from txt file and post them to textview item

Tags: java, android, sorting, textview

I am reading from txt file some strings.TextView shows me:"score=10" "score=1""score=5""score=11"
I want to sort this like:TextView shows:"score=1" "score=5""score=10""score=11"
I dont know how to sort this strings.this are not ints.
Can u Help me with an example ? Or can u see my code?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wyniki);

    final TextView scores = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    final Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    String saved_scores = readText();
    if (saved_scores.length()>0){
        scores.setText(saved_scores);}

    sort();

    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


             final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/cos/Wynik.txt");
            if (f.exists()){
                f.delete(); 

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                scores.setText(null);

            }
        }
    });


}

public String readText(){
     //this is your text
     StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
 try{

     final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/cos/Wynik.txt");
     FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);
     BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));
              String readString = "";
     //just reading each line and pass it on the debugger  
     while((readString = buf.readLine())!= null){
        Log.d("line: ", readString);
        text.append(readString + "\n");
               }
     buf.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

     e.printStackTrace();

  } catch (IOException e){

     e.printStackTrace();

  }
         return text.toString();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "score=" part of each line in the text file, and for each line check if the remaining content is a valid number - if so, store that as an integer in a collection. Once you're done with reading the text file, you can just sort the collection and use the data in whatever fashion you want in your TextView.

Comment: List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     data.add(Integer.parseInt(scores.getText().toString()));
     Collections.sort(data);
     scores.setText(data.toString());
sth like this ? But java throws that my numbers in txt are not int. and close apk.

Comment: Fine. Do the rest then. It's still good practice to check in code if the content is valid numbers.

Comment: what if my txt file  contains numbers +\n ?

Comment: That's just a line break. Just read each line of the text file, convert it to an integer value and add it to a collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following
Scanner Reader=new Scanner(fileName);
In a for loop read all the integers from using Reader.nextInt() function.